# Could ReSharper highlight errors instead of underlining them?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, resharper

R# has two ways of notifying me of problems in my code. One is highlighting the whole text, which I love and which could be seen from the far end of the room:

[image: i]

And the other is ugly curly underlining:

[image: i]

And so far I haven't found the color which make the second one at least close in its visibility to the first one. It's just invisible on the dark background.

I also know that first one (nice) is called `Resharper Error Highlighting` and the second one is `Resharper Underlined Error Highlighting`.

Could R# always be nice and highlight the errors so I could see them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can change the colours for the underlines, but not how it affects the text, because it doesn't touch the text - it only draws the underline.

(And I've kicked off an internal discussion as to why we have two different ways of showing errors.)

Comment: Thanks! Would it be easy to write an R# extension which highlights everything?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd go with easy, but I think it's possible. You can hook the events for when text documents are opened and use the `IDocumentMarkupManager` to get an instance of `IDocumentMarkup` for that document. You can then subscribe to the `Changed` event that will tell you when a new highlight has been added/removed. You should be able to add a new Visual Studio highlight to the document in response. (You'll also need to unsubscribe the event when the document closes). The [devguide](https://jetbrains.com/resharper/devguide) has details on how to get started with plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Class names are colored as classes, methods as methods, string as strings, and so on — and if some word does not look like any of those, then R# paints it red to indicate that it can't understand the reference. Once the reference is known, it gets colored after to its kind.

If there're further errors, they're wavy-underlined without spoiling the text color. There might be looong highlightings, and usually we don't want the text under them to look all plain red. Also I believe the errors shan't be standing out too much, or they will distract from the text one is trying to correct. Why, if the error is under the caret, you'll see it anyway. And if it's not, you often don't care looking at it until you jump there with Alt+PgDn or Alt+Shift+PgDn or by clicking the error indicator at the top-right corner.

What is the scenario for seeing all the errors?

Making the wavy underline brighter is a viable option though. Should we have an option to make the line thicker? Or maybe make a transparent red overlay?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! My problem with underlining is that I just can't see it. I keep solution-wide analysis off, and so I often make a mistake and can't notice it (because the underlining is too faint) until I build/run tests. Which is pain, because ReSharper knew that I had error by the time I press build. I like your idea about making the underline brighter/thicker.

Comment: Thing as, as I see it (even in the black theme) it's visible enough here, so probably it should not be tweaked to be brighter by default — and such a setting would be hard to place in the UI. To be sure — is the editor at 100% zoom? Does setting the color to #FF8040 or greater help a bit? Is the display or graphics adapter gamma set up such that darker colors are not dimmed?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, the color is better, but it's still far from the HEY YOU FIX THIS ERROR RIGHT NOW!!!!!11 which is the level of visibility I'm looking for. Anyway, I agree with your argument that highlighting all the text could be an overkill. I though I'd give solution-wide analysis another chance. If it works for me, than error highlight visibility won't be matter too much.

Comment: For the current file, there's also the local status icon available in the top-right corner. hift+Alt+PgDn would jump to the next error location, if any, even without Solution-Wide Analysis. As for SWA, for me its only problem (even on huge solutions) is that it takes ages to re-analyze when I switch the source control to a totally different branch. Without such massive changes, it pretty much just works.

Comment: thanks for per-file status icon tip (NOTE: you need to turn on Marker Bar to see it).

Comment: It should be on by default if you install R# no a stock VS — but can be turned off in R# settings (or maybe in VS settings, because it's now optionally combined with the advanced scrollbar).